# Removing Carpet and Linoleum for one unified flooring of LVP

Tags: flooring, removal, vinyl-flooring, renovation

I have a house from 2019 that I am planning on ripping out the carpet in the living room and linoleum in the kitchen to make one unified flooring of LVP. I have yet to start ripping things out yet, but I've noticed the linoleum has a very thin sheet of wood that its attached to, instead of directly glued to the OSB.

My question is, should I get an underlayment for the currently carpeted living room (considerably  smaller than the kitchen area) that matches the height of the current linoleum and lay my flooring onto that? Or should I try to get back down to the base OSB and work off that? Or would ripping up all the linoleum be best?

I am not sure how the linoleum is attached to the OSB, but I imagine based on how easy/hard that is to fully remove will dictate how I move forward.

Thank you!

Comment: If the linoleum is in decent shape, smooth and flat, I would probably leave it.

Comment: To many TLA for me to understand

Comment: LVP Luxury vinyl planking (fake hardwood flooring),  OSB oriented strand board (half way between plywood and chipboard) the subfloor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed many a LVP floor in my investment homes, personal residence and for customers. LVP can be very forgiving if they are good quality and min of 5.5mm thick. If the difference in height between the linoleum  and the floor bare of carpet is 1/8 inch or less you can use leveling compound made for wood subfloors to ease that transition. The new LVP will have to cover that transition at the doorway/ opening perpendicular and not parallel to the opening. If the difference in height is greater than 1/8 find an underlayment close to the same thickness that is rated for use with LVP flooring. There are some that add just a bit of cushioning and it helps with sound transfer as well.
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Ripped the carpet up today and see the linoleum is glued onto a 1/4" plywood piece, so I'm thinking of getting a 6mm cork underlayment to fill the "gap" (was looking at plywood, but its so darn expensive right now).

Comment: The 6mm or 1/4" cork is a good idea.